# JavaScript functions just not working

Tags: javascript, html, web

i have this sample site that i do for practicing and i added a video to it with some buttons with JavaScript.
when i run the script inside the HTML file its running great, but if i'm trying to run it from the .js file it just doesn't work and the bottons won't do anything.
any thoughts?

**html** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Blue Developer Directory</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="ad" width="420" height="350"  controls>
          <source src="video/ad.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Please update your browser
        </video>
        <div style="width:400px;"> 
              <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 
              <button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
              <button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
              <button onclick="makeNormal()">Normal</button>
        </div> 

</body>
```

**Javascript**:

```
var myVideo=document.getElementById(ad); 
function playPause(){ 
if (myVideo.paused) 
  myVideo.play(); 
else 
  myVideo.pause(); 
} 

function makeBig(){ 
myVideo.width=560; 
} 

function makeSmall(){ 
myVideo.width=320; 
} 

function makeNormal(){ 
myVideo.width=420; 
}
```

Comment: Move the script tag to the end of the body.

Comment: Change either `myVideo.paused` or `myVideo.pause` so they reference the same thing.

Comment: @DevlshOne - [`paused`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974756(v=vs.85).aspx) is a DOM property of a [`<video>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772959(v=vs.85).aspx) element and [`pause()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975193(v=vs.85).aspx) is a DOM method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue:

```
var myVideo=document.getElementById(ad);
```

Needs quotes:

```
var myVideo=document.getElementById('ad');
```

I would also remove the inline event handlers and set up the function calls like so:

```
<button id="play">Play/Pause</button>
```

And the JS:

```
var play=document.getElementById('play');
play.onclick = function() {
    playPause();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reference an element before it has been added to the document.  Wait until the document is loaded.  And you need to wrap the id in quotes.

```
var myVideo;
onload = function(){
    myVideo=document.getElementById("ad");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As already stated you probably trying to access elements before they are ready; I'm assuming you placing you soure code in the head. This can be fixed by placing the source at the bottom of the document or waiting for the onload. Here is a jQuery example of what you're trying to achieve:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Blue Developer Directory</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="ad" width="420" height="350"  controls>
      <source src="video/ad.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Please update your browser
    </video>
    <div style="width:400px;"> 
          <button id="playPause">Play/Pause</button> 
          <button id="makeBig">Big</button>
          <button id="makeSmall">Small</button>
          <button id="makeNormal">Normal</button>
    </div> 

</body>
```

Source Code

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
  var playPauseFunction = function (e) { ... };
  var makeBigFunction = function (e){ ... };
  .
  .
  $('#playPause').on('click', playFunction);
  $('#makeBig').on('click',makeBigFunction);
  .
  .
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i've got it!!
i had a height setting of the whole block on my CSS file that prevent the function to work.
now it works great.
thanks anyway.